# Shiv'a Ushlosh Meyot - mi yodeya?

Tags: number, mi-yodeya-series

### Who knows three hundred and seven?

### ?שבעה ושלוש מאות - מי יודע

In the spirit of the song ["Echad - mi yodeya"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echad_Mi_Yodea), please post interesting and significant Jewish facts about the number 307.

Check out [mi-yodeya-series](/questions/tagged/mi-yodeya-series) for the previous three hundred and six entries in this ongoing series.

Please include sources for your information wherever possible, as with all other answers on this site.

Comment: I wonder if any Europeans on the site can come up with a lazy gematria? Maybe they would ask one of our matriarchs for help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Avrohom gave birth to Yitzchak at 100. Yitchak gave birth to Yaakov at 60. Yaakov lived for 147 years.

100 + 60 + 147 = 307

The era of the Avos lasted 307 years.

Comment: +1 Why are the komatzes in Avrohom transliterated as 'o' but those in Yitzchak and Avos transliterated as 'a'?

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tishrei

> On the 1st of Tishrei, (the **307th** day of the Great Flood), Noah
>   dispatched a dove from the ark, for the third time. When the dove
>   returned carrying an olive branch, this is how Noah knew that the
>   flood was drained from the earth. On that day, Noah removed the roof
>   of the ark; but Noah and his family, and all the animals, remained in
>   the ark for another 57 days, until the 27th of Cheshvan, when the
>   surface of the earth was completely dry and God commanded them to
>   leave the ark and resettle and repopulate the earth.

Comment: How do they know it was the 307th day? Perhaps there were different malei and chaseir months then we have in our calendar.

Comment: I think this wiki is incorrect. Bereshit 8:13 says that on the 1st of the first month (=Tishrei acc. to R. Eliezer) "the waters dried up from upon the earth, and Noah removed the covering of the ark, and he saw, and behold, the surface of the ground had dried up" - which isn't necessarily connected to the previos pasuk 8:12 concerning how Noah sent  a dove for the third time......

Comment: Indeed, according to my calculation, Noch sent the dove for the third time on the *310th day* of the flood - which works out to be the 2nd of Tishrei. ... (regarding @DoubleAA's point - it seems that Rashi is ok with using Cheshvan as 29 days, Kislev as 30 days Tevet - 29 and so on -- see Rashi Bereshit 8:3)

Answer (score 1):

> וְעַל יָדָם חֵיל צָבָא שְׁלֹשׁ מֵאוֹת אֶלֶף וְשִׁבְעַת אֲלָפִים וַחֲמֵשׁ מֵאוֹת עוֹשֵׂי מִלְחָמָה בְּכֹחַ חָיִל לַעְזֹר לַמֶּלֶךְ עַל הָאוֹיֵב

‏—[דברי הימים ב כו](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%93%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%94%D7%99%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%91_%D7%9B%D7%95) יג

Answer (score 0):

According to [Esther Benbassa](http://books.google.com/books?id=G_00s10twe4C&pg=PA80), 307 of the [*cahiers de doléances*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cahiers_de_dol%C3%A9ances) complained about the Jews.